# long short portfolio sharpe ratio

Tags: programming, returns, portfolio, sharpe-ratio, longshort

What is the proper way to caluclate sharpe ratio for the long short portfolio? When I calculate daily return with no cost, I use this formula: (return for long k.mean()+ (-1)*(return for short k.mean())/2
So can I use this formula to get daily sharpe ratio?: all daily return with no cost/all daily return's std
If this is wrong, what is the right formula?
And how can I get the annualized sharpe ratio of long short portfolio?
I tried this: one daily return/all daily return's std for each date and divide by date number

Comment: Isn't the Sharpe ratio just a function of a series of historical returns?

Comment: (1) Find the daily returns (2) Find their mean and standard deviation and compute the (daily) Sharpe Ratio (3) Annualize the sharpe ratio by multiplying by $\sqrt{252}$ the sqrt of the number of trading days per year

Comment: Can you clarify what your formula means? What is k.mean, where is the variance? (return for long k.mean()+ (-1)*(return for short k.mean())/2

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume stock "A" yields a 5% return and stock "B" yields a 6% return, they both have standard deviations of 10% (per annum) and a correlation factor of 0.5.
You decide to short stock "A" and long stock "B", let's assume you short "A" for an equivalent of 50% of your portfolio's value and use the proceeds (including your portfolio's value) to buy "B" for an equivalent of 150% of your initial margin. You have weights -50% in A and 150% in B.

By doing -50% * 5% + 150% * 6%, you will find your portfolio's return.
Your standard deviation for only two stocks can be simply calculated by finding the square root of the ["portfolio variance formula"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BGd7Ugb-YRM), keep in mind that you must know your correlation factor.

return : 6.5%

std : 3.5%

risk free rate: (let's say 2%)

Then,
Sharpe = (6.5% - 2%) / 3.5% = 1.29

If your values are daily, then the sharpe ratio can be roughly annualized by multiplying with the square root of 252 (number of trading days).